# Merging two linked lists - how does the dummy node get updated?

Tags: python, sorting, merge, linked-list

Merge two sorted linked lists and return it as a sorted list. The list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.

we have l1:

```
ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}
```

and l2:

```
ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}
```

I merge them using the following code:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        print(l1)
        print(l2)
        out = ListNode(-1)
        temp = out
        while l1 and l2:
            if (l1.val < l2.val):
                temp.next = l1
                l1 = l1.next
            else:
                temp.next = l2
                l2 = l2.next
            temp = temp.next
        print(out)
```

This is what out is:

```
ListNode{val: -1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}}
```

My question is how is `out` getting updated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`out` gets mutated in the first iteration of the `while` loop.

It may help to visualise it.

Just before the loop starts, we have created a dummy node (with value -1) and referred to it with `out` and `temp`:

```
                   l1
                   ↓
                 ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
                 │ val:  1    │    │ val:  2    │    │ val:  4    │
                 │ next: ────────> │ next: ────────> │ next: None │
 out             └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ val:  -1   │
│ next: None │
└────────────┘
  ↑
 temp            ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
                 │ val:  1    │    │ val:  3    │    │ val:  4    │
                 │ next: ────────> │ next: ────────> │ next: None │
                 └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
                   ↑
                   l2
```

In the first iteration we get into the `else` block, where `temp` is *mutated*. Since `temp` and `out` reference the same object, this mutates `out`.

```
                   l1
                   ↓
                 ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
                 │ val:  1    │    │ val:  2    │    │ val:  4    │
                 │ next: ────────> │ next: ────────> │ next: None │
 out             └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ val:  -1   │
│ next: ──────┐
└────────────┘│
  ↑           │
 temp         │  ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
              │  │ val:  1    │    │ val:  3    │    │ val:  4    │
              └> │ next: ────────> │ next: ────────> │ next: None │
                 └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
                   ↑
                   l2
```

After this update, both `l2` and `temp` are "moved" to refer to their successor. This ends the first iteration:

```
                   l1
                   ↓
                 ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
                 │ val:  1    │    │ val:  2    │    │ val:  4    │
                 │ next: ────────> │ next: ────────> │ next: None │
 out             └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
  ↓
┌────────────┐
│ val:  -1   │
│ next: ──────┐
└────────────┘│
              │
              │  ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
              │  │ val:  1    │    │ val:  3    │    │ val:  4    │
              └> │ next: ────────> │ next: ────────> │ next: None │
                 └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
                   ↑                 ↑
                  temp               l2
```

We don't really have to continue through the algorithm, as from now on `out` will not be mutated again: that job has been done. But let's just continue with one more iteration (the second iteration). There we get into the `if` block, and `temp` gets mutated again (but this time, it is not a synonym for `out`):

```
                   l1
                   ↓
                 ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
                 │ val:  1    │    │ val:  2    │    │ val:  4    │
              ┌> │ next: ────────> │ next: ────────> │ next: None │
 out          │  └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
  ↓           └────────────────┐
┌────────────┐                 │
│ val:  -1   │                 │
│ next: ──────┐                │
└────────────┘│                │
              │                │
              │  ┌────────────┐│   ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
              │  │ val:  1    ││   │ val:  3    │    │ val:  4    │
              └> │ next: ──────┘   │ next: ────────> │ next: None │
                 └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
                   ↑                 ↑
                  temp               l2
```

...and both `l1` and `temp` move to their successors:

```
                  temp               l1
                   ↓                 ↓
                 ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
                 │ val:  1    │    │ val:  2    │    │ val:  4    │
              ┌> │ next: ────────> │ next: ────────> │ next: None │
 out          │  └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
  ↓           └────────────────┐
┌────────────┐                 │
│ val:  -1   │                 │
│ next: ──────┐                │
└────────────┘│                │
              │                │
              │  ┌────────────┐│   ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
              │  │ val:  1    ││   │ val:  3    │    │ val:  4    │
              └> │ next: ──────┘   │ next: ────────> │ next: None │
                 └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
                                     ↑
                                     l2
```

Continuing like that, `temp` will remain the tail of the resulting list that is being wired. After the last iteration, we will have this:

```
                                                       l1
                                                       ↓
                 ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
                 │ val:  1    │    │ val:  2    │    │ val:  4    │
              ┌> │ next: ────────> │ next: ──────┐   │ next: None │
 out          │  └────────────┘    └────────────┘│   └────────────┘
  ↓           └────────────────┐ ┌───────────────┘
┌────────────┐                 │ │                                
│ val:  -1   │                 │ │                                
│ next: ──────┐                │ │                                
└────────────┘│                │ │                                
              │                │ │                                
              │  ┌────────────┐│ │ ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
              │  │ val:  1    ││ │ │ val:  3    │    │ val:  4    │
              └> │ next: ──────┘ └>│ next: ────────> │ next: None │
                 └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
                                                       ↑                
                                                      temp
```

The job is not entirely done, as some code is missing from the snippet you have posted. When the `while` loop exits, one of `l1` or `l2` will not be `None`, and that represents a part that still needs to be appended to the resulting list. As `temp` refers to the current tail of the resulting list, we should set its `next` reference to either `l1` or `l2` -- whichever is not `None`.

So the code should have something like the following statement after the loop:

```
temp.next = l1 or l2
```

...which results in:

```
                                                       l1
                                                       ↓
                 ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
                 │ val:  1    │    │ val:  2    │    │ val:  4    │
              ┌> │ next: ────────> │ next: ──────┐ ┌>│ next: None │
 out          │  └────────────┘    └────────────┘│ │ └────────────┘
  ↓           └────────────────┐ ┌───────────────┘ └───────────────┐
┌────────────┐                 │ │                                 │
│ val:  -1   │                 │ │                                 │
│ next: ──────┐                │ │                                 │
└────────────┘│                │ │                                 │
              │                │ │                                 │
              │  ┌────────────┐│ │ ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐│
              │  │ val:  1    ││ │ │ val:  3    │    │ val:  4    ││
              └> │ next: ──────┘ └>│ next: ────────> │ next: ──────┘
                 └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
                                                       ↑                
                                                      temp
```

And finally, the function should *return* the result. As `out` refers to a dummy node, we should not just return `out`, but `out.next`:

```
return out.next
```

The returned list reference will be to this:

```
           ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
           │ val:  1    │    │ val:  2    │    │ val:  4    │
        ┌> │ next: ────────> │ next: ──────┐ ┌>│ next: None │
        │  └────────────┘    └────────────┘│ │ └────────────┘
        └────────────────┐ ┌───────────────┘ └───────────────┐
                         │ │                                 │
           ┌────────────┐│ │ ┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐│
           │ val:  1    ││ │ │ val:  3    │    │ val:  4    ││
returned → │ next: ──────┘ └>│ next: ────────> │ next: ──────┘
           └────────────┘    └────────────┘    └────────────┘
```

I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Yes it does, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, you don't even need any temporary nodes. You can relink the existing nodes which makes it much simpler:

```
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        if not (l1 and l2):
            return l1 or l2
        if l2.val < l1.val:
            l1, l2 = l2, l1
        l1.next = self.mergeTwoLists(l1.next, l2)
        return l1
```