# Merge Two Sorted Lists. confused about working of "=" operator in python

Tags: python, linked-list, operators

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        dummy=ListNode()
        tail=dummy
        while list1 and list2:
            if list1.val<list2.val:
                tail.next=list1
                list1=list1.next
            else:
                tail.next=list2
                list2=list2.next
            tail=tail.next
        if list1:
            tail.next=list1
        elif list2:
            tail.next = list2
        return dummy.next
```

The  `=` operator doesn't create a new object rather It only creates a new variable that shares the reference of the original object.

- Why is there a difference between `dummy.next` value and `tail.next` value?
- At each step the new variable is modified isn't the old variable also modified?

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is there a difference between `dummy.next` value and `tail.next` value?

In the *first* iteration (only) `dummy` and `tail` reference the same object. So when `tail.next` is assigned a node (like `list1` or `list2`), this affects the object that both `tail` and `dummy` reference.

But then `tail = tail.next` is executed, and this makes `tail` reference a different object than `dummy` references.

> At each step the new variable is modified isn't the old variable also modified?

No, we should distinguish *assignment* to a name from *mutating* the object that a name references. The first looks like `tail =`, the second looks like `tail.next =`.

Assignment to a name never alters what another name references. So the first time `tail = tail.next` is executed, is when `tail` and `dummy` depart from eachother. In this program, `dummy` never "moves": it keeps referencing the dummy node. But `tail` walks away from it, always referencing the node that was most recently created.

See also [this visualisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69924548/5459839) of merging two linked lists.