# LeetCode Merge sorted linked list -- how does this code work?

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

I’m working on the LeetCode problem: [merge 2 sorted linked lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/):

> You are given the heads of two sorted linked lists `list1` and `list2`.
>
> Merge the two lists in a one **sorted** list. The list should be made by splicing together the nodes of the first two lists.
>
> Return *the head of the merged linked list.*

I couldn’t solve it, so I looked at an answer that worked. I’d like to dissect it and learn:

```
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        cur = dummy = ListNode()  # *
        while list1 and list2:  # **            
            if list1.val < list2.val:
                cur.next = list1
                list1, cur = list1.next, list1  # ***
            else:
                cur.next = list2
                list2, cur = list2.next, list2
                
        if list1 or list2:  # ****
            cur.next = list1 if list1 else list2
            
        return dummy.next  # *****
```

The parts with asterisks are where I have questions:

1. is `ListNode()` a kind of function? what does it do?
2. does `while list1 and list2` mean : if `list1 and list2` is not blank?
3. `list1, cur=list1.next, list1`, is this supposed to mean that the entire `list1` equals to the next value in `list1`? And the current node equals to the entire `list1`?
4. does `if list1 or list2: cur.next = list1 if list1 else list2` mean that if either list is empty, the next node will be the non empty list?
5. for : `return dummy.next`, I thought you’re supposed to return an entire merged linked list, isn’t returning `dummy.next` just returning  one node?

I’m new to linked lists

Answer (score 0):

> is `ListNode()` a kind of function? what does it do?

`ListNode` is a class. The template code that is presented to you has a comment block that has its definition:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
```

With `ListNode()` the constructor (`__init__`) is called. As no arguments are passed, the created node will have its `val` attribute set to 0 and its `next` attribute to `None`.

> does `while list1 and list2` mean : if list1 and list2 is not blank?

Since `list1` and `list2` are either instances of the `ListNode` class or are `None`, this condition checks that neither is `None` and the loop will repeat as long as that is the case. When at least one of them becomes `None` this condition will end the loop.

> `list1, cur=list1.next, list1`, is this supposed to mean that the entire `list1` equals to the next value in `list1`? And the current node equals to the entire `list1`?

This is a tuple assignment, i.e. two assignments happen. You could write the following equivalent code:

```
cur = list1
list1 = list1.next
```

The assignment to `cur` means that `cur` now references the (first) node of `list1`.
The assignment to `list1` means that it will reference the *successor* of that node. You could say that `list1` now references a list that has one less node.

> does this mean that if either list is empty, the next node will be the non empty list?

`if list1 or list2` is executed after the loop. At that moment we know that at least `list1` or `list2` is `None`. This `if` checks if there is still one that is not `None`. If so, those nodes still need to be added to the merged result. And that is achieved with:

```
cur.next = list1 if list1 else list2
```

`cur` is always referencing the last node in the merged list. By assigning to `cur.next` we will append the remaining nodes to the merged list. The assigned value is either `list1` or `list2` whichever is the non-empty list. It could also have been written as:

```
cur.next = list1 or list2
```

> `return dummy.next`, I thought you’re supposed to return an entire merged linked list, isn’t returning `dummy.next` just returning  one node?

Initially, `dummy.next` is `None`, but as `cur` is initialised as a reference to that node and in the loop `cur.next` is assigned a node, we actually update *that* `next` attribute. Then the loop makes `cur` reference *that* node, and in a next iteration *that* node also gets a `next`...etc, and so the merged list is being chained together.

You may also want to read [Merging two linked lists - how does the dummy node get updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69924548/5459839)

Comment: i asked a separate question to see if i can get more clarification and make linked list more simple so i can understand, . so for the template code in this question: why would we create a function that passes no arguments? and is the template function generally required to create another function that can traverse through a linked list?

Comment: whyis the value set to 0 and next set to none

Comment: There are many reasons why you would call a function without arguments. In this case the function returns a new node object. I have explained in my answer what happens when no arguments are passed. The value is set to 0 because the value of that node is not relevant for what this node is used for. The `next` reference is set to `None` because the node starts by being alone -- not connected to another node. That connection is set later in the loop, when the value of that `next` is changed to a reference to another node.

Comment: Did you read the post that I linked to at the end? It visualises the whole process. I think it is quite helpful to understand what happens. (In that post the node gets value -1 instead of 0, but it doesn't matter).